# Go one folder up in Unity build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to move one folder up in my Unity build such that the structure is as follows:

```
MainFolder -> UnityApp.exe
```

The directory structure is:

```
ParentFolder/MainFolder/UnityApp.exe
```

Now how do I go to my "ParentFolder"?

```
private string GetDirectory() {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        if (RootFolder)
            return Path.Combine ("C:/Users/admin/source/ParentFolder/");
        return RootFolder;

#else
        var oneLevelUp = Application.dataPath + "/../"; //Here is where it is not working
        if (RootFolder)
            return Path.Combine (oneLevelUp);
        return RootFolder;
#endif
    }
```

I can get the path to work in my editor because I am specifying the path, but what about in my build? That is causing problems. I cannot access it.

Comment: I didnt know path.combine took one parameter. It makes no sense it would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [Path.GetDirectoryName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getdirectoryname) return the parent directory's path :

```cs
var path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019";
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
// Output - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
```

This work also with relative path :

```
var path = @"Level1\Level2\Level3\Level4";
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
// Output - Level1\Level2\Level3
```

In your case :

```cs
var oneLevelUp = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.dataPath);
```

Comment: Will I get to ParentFolder? I actually do not need the string. I need the path. Will this provide me with it?

Comment: Yes, if you pass a directory's path in `Path.GetDirectoryName` else this return the parent directory's path. I don't understand the point about string or path. A path is generally stored in a variable of type `string`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the right way to do this. Using Path.Combine():

```
using System.IO;
 
// Application.dataPath returns something like C:/MyWork/UnityProject/Asset
// back 1 level using "../" to get to project path
 
// C:/MyWork/UnityProject/
string projectFolder = Path.Combine( Application.dataPath, "../" );
 
// C:/MyWork/UnityProject/ProjectSettings
string settingFolder = Path.Combine( Application.dataPath, "../ProjectSettings" );
 
// back 2 levels to out of project path
// C:/MyWork/
string outside = Path.Combine( Application.dataPath, "../../" );
```